# Ctrl + Click do Sublime Text no VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublime-text

No Sublime Text tem uma função onde seguramos o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> e clicamos em um texto e ela é selecionada.

Existe essa função no VS Code?

Segue imagem de exemplo onde selecionei 2 textos diferentes no Sublime.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara existem pelo meno 3 ou mais formas de fazer isso no VS Code, sem necessariamente ter que customizar qualquer atalho ou mudar configuração.

**Opção 1**

A primeira é segurando <kbd>Alt</kbd> e <kbd>clicando 3x</kbd> em algum caractere da linha (o primeiro clique marca o cursor, o segundo clique seleciona a palavra e o terceiro clique seleciona a frase)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Opção 2**

Nessa opção pressionando <kbd>Alt</kbd> vc clica nas linhas que quer marcar, depois aperta <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> e vai selecionar a linha inteira

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Atalho  <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd>** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Opção 3**

Nessa opção pressionando <kbd>Alt</kbd> vc clica no início de cada linha que quer selecionar e depois aperta <kbd>Shift + End</kbd>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

**Não existe** e o VS Code ainda não suporta customização de atalhos de mouse.

Dê uma olhada [nesta lista de atalhos do SublimeText que o VS Code não suporta](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3776) (do criador da extensão "*Sublime Text Keymap and Settings Importer*" para VS Code).

Esta função é a primeira na lista, eis a *issue* no GitHub do VS Code: [*Allow customization of mouse shortcuts #3130*](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3130).

Comment: Entendi, boa resposta, eu instalei essa extensão e rodou como queria, vou usa-la até quem sabe o vscode implementar essas funções.

Answer (score 0):

Na versão atual do VSCode (1.33.1) você pode segurar `Alt + (Clique duplo)` em textos para selecioná-los.